# Redirect subdirectory to subdomain and non-www to www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

let's suppose we have a domain root.com 
I have added these line in the htaccess to redirect non-www to www :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I have also a sub-domain : demo.root.com so I have added a htaccess in the sub-directory root/demo and added some line to redirect the sub-directory to sub-domain to avoid direct access to the sub-directory using root.com/demo or www.root.com/demo here is the added code :

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^root.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.root.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/demo/(.*)$ http://demo.root.com/$1
```

now the result is :

- Redirect non-www to www of the main domain root.com
- Redirect sub-directory /root/demo to sub-domain demo.root.com

The problem is :

using this url: root.com/demo (the non-www version) won't redirect me to demo.root.com , maybe because there is two redirection:

- From non-www to www
- From sub-directory to sub-domain

it seems that the combination won't work

What I want ?

Combination of :

- Be able to redirect the main domain from non-www to www without issues in the sub-domain
- Redirect the sub-directory to sub-domain

Answer (score 0):

Keep both these rules in your main `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^demo(/.*|)$ http://demo.root.com$1 [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Remove your existing rules from `demo/.htaccess`.

Comment: Thank you for your help but when I try your solution when I try to access the main domain www.root.com it show me the 500 error

Comment: Can you see reported error from your error.log and tell me what is the error.

Comment: it shows : 

"/home/dir/public_html/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters"

Note that I use the htaccess of Joomla

Comment: Oh you have Joomla too. Make sure to put these rule on top i.e before regular Joomla rules. Also please tell me which URL you tried to test this rule?

Comment: I just retested this code on my Apache and it worked file. Please follow my suggestions above and do tell me which URL you were using in testing.